# AttributeError: module 'gspread' has no attribute 'service_account' regardless of version

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-colaboratory, gspread

i am trying to use the gspread module on google colaboratory but i keep receiving an error. The code looks like this;

```
!pip install --upgrade gspread==5.9.0
import pandas as pd

import gspread

client = gspread.service_account(filename='[location_to_the_json_file]')

wb_1 = client.open([location_to_the_google_sheet_doc])
```

i guessed that this wouldnt work with an older version of gspread so i installed the recent version but its still not working

These are all the modules/packages installed(gotten from pip freeze)

*>     absl-py==1.4.0

> ```
> alabaster==0.7.13
> albumentations==1.2.1
> altair==4.2.2
> anyio==3.6.2
> appdirs==1.4.4
> argon2-cffi==21.3.0
> argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
> array-record==0.2.0
> arviz==0.15.1
> astropy==5.2.2
> astunparse==1.6.3
> attrs==23.1.0
> audioread==3.0.0
> autograd==1.5
> Babel==2.12.1
> backcall==0.2.0
> beautifulsoup4==4.11.2
> bleach==6.0.0
> blis==0.7.9
> blosc2==2.0.0
> bokeh==2.4.3
> branca==0.6.0
> build==0.10.0
> CacheControl==0.12.11
> cached-property==1.5.2
> cachetools==5.3.0
> catalogue==2.0.8
> certifi==2022.12.7
> cffi==1.15.1
> chardet==4.0.0
> charset-normalizer==2.0.12
> chex==0.1.7
> click==8.1.3
> cloudpickle==2.2.1
> cmake==3.25.2
> cmdstanpy==1.1.0
> colorcet==3.0.1
> colorlover==0.3.0
> community==1.0.0b1
> confection==0.0.4
> cons==0.4.5
> contextlib2==0.6.0.post1
> contourpy==1.0.7
> convertdate==2.4.0
> cryptography==40.0.2
> cufflinks==0.17.3
> cvxopt==1.3.0
> cvxpy==1.3.1
> cycler==0.11.0
> cymem==2.0.7
> Cython==0.29.34
> dask==2022.12.1
> datascience==0.17.6
> db-dtypes==1.1.1
> dbus-python==1.2.16
> debugpy==1.6.6
> decorator==4.4.2
> defusedxml==0.7.1
> distributed==2022.12.1
> dlib==19.24.1
> dm-tree==0.1.8
> docutils==0.16
> dopamine-rl==4.0.6
> duckdb==0.7.1
> earthengine-api==0.1.350
> easydict==1.10
> ecos==2.0.12
> editdistance==0.6.2
> en-core-web-sm 
> entrypoints==0.4
> ephem==4.1.4
> et-xmlfile==1.1.0
> etils==1.2.0
> etuples==0.3.8
> exceptiongroup==1.1.1
> fastai==2.7.12
> fastcore==1.5.29
> fastdownload==0.0.7
> fastjsonschema==2.16.3
> fastprogress==1.0.3
> fastrlock==0.8.1
> filelock==3.12.0
> firebase-admin==5.3.0
> Flask==2.2.4
> flatbuffers==23.3.3
> flax==0.6.9
> folium==0.14.0
> fonttools==4.39.3
> frozendict==2.3.7
> fsspec==2023.4.0
> future==0.18.3
> gast==0.4.0
> GDAL==3.3.2
> gdown==4.6.6
> gensim==4.3.1
> geographiclib==2.0
> geopy==2.3.0
> gin-config==0.5.0
> glob2==0.7
> google==2.0.3
> google-api-core==2.11.0
> google-api-python-client==2.84.0
> google-auth==2.17.3
> google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
> google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0
> google-cloud-bigquery==3.9.0
> google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.19.1
> google-cloud-core==2.3.2
> google-cloud-datastore==2.15.1
> google-cloud-firestore==2.11.0
> google-cloud-language==2.9.1
> google-cloud-storage==2.8.0
> google-cloud-translate==3.11.1
> google-colab
> google-crc32c==1.5.0
> google-pasta==0.2.0
> google-resumable-media==2.5.0
> googleapis-common-protos==1.59.0
> googledrivedownloader==0.4
> graphviz==0.20.1
> greenlet==2.0.2
> grpcio==1.54.0
> grpcio-status==1.48.2
> gspread==3.4.2
> gspread-dataframe==3.0.8
> gym==0.25.2
> gym-notices==0.0.8
> h5netcdf==1.1.0
> h5py==3.8.0
> holidays==0.25
> holoviews==1.15.4
> html5lib==1.1
> httpimport==1.3.0
> httplib2==0.21.0
> humanize==4.6.0
> hyperopt==0.2.7
> idna==3.4
> imageio==2.25.1
> imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.8
> imagesize==1.4.1
> imbalanced-learn==0.10.1
> imgaug==0.4.0
> importlib-resources==5.12.0
> imutils==0.5.4
> inflect==6.0.4
> iniconfig==2.0.0
> intel-openmp==2023.1.0
> ipykernel==5.5.6
> ipython==7.34.0
> ipython-genutils==0.2.0
> ipython-sql==0.4.1
> ipywidgets==7.7.1
> itsdangerous==2.1.2
> jax==0.4.10
> jaxlib 
> jieba==0.42.1
> Jinja2==3.1.2
> joblib==1.2.0
> jsonpickle==3.0.1
> jsonschema==4.3.3
> jupyter-client==6.1.12
> jupyter-console==6.1.0
> jupyter-server==1.24.0
> jupyter_core==5.3.0
> jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
> jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.7
> kaggle==1.5.13
> keras==2.12.0
> kiwisolver==1.4.4
> korean-lunar-calendar==0.3.1
> langcodes==3.3.0
> lazy_loader==0.2
> libclang==16.0.0
> librosa==0.10.0.post2
> lightgbm==3.3.5
> lit==16.0.5
> llvmlite==0.39.1
> locket==1.0.0
> logical-unification==0.4.5
> LunarCalendar==0.0.9
> lxml==4.9.2
> Markdown==3.4.3
> markdown-it-py==2.2.0
> MarkupSafe==2.1.2
> matplotlib==3.7.1
> matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
> matplotlib-venn==0.11.9
> mdurl==0.1.2
> miniKanren==1.0.3
> missingno==0.5.2
> mistune==0.8.4
> mizani==0.8.1
> mkl==2019.0
> ml-dtypes==0.1.0
> mlxtend==0.14.0
> more-itertools==9.1.0
> moviepy==1.0.3
> mpmath==1.3.0
> msgpack==1.0.5
> multipledispatch==0.6.0
> multitasking==0.0.11
> murmurhash==1.0.9
> music21==8.1.0
> natsort==8.3.1
> nbclient==0.7.4
> nbconvert==6.5.4
> nbformat==5.8.0
> nest-asyncio==1.5.6
> networkx==3.1
> nibabel==3.0.2
> nltk==3.8.1
> notebook==6.4.8
> numba==0.56.4
> numexpr==2.8.4
> numpy==1.22.4
> oauth2client==4.1.3
> oauthlib==3.2.2
> opencv-contrib-python==4.7.0.72
> opencv-python==4.7.0.72
> opencv-python-headless==4.7.0.72
> openpyxl==3.0.10
> opt-einsum==3.3.0
> optax==0.1.5
> orbax-checkpoint==0.2.1
> osqp==0.6.2.post8
> packaging==23.1
> palettable==3.3.3
> pandas==1.5.3
> pandas-datareader==0.10.0
> pandas-gbq==0.17.9
> pandocfilters==1.5.0
> panel==0.14.4
> param==1.13.0
> parso==0.8.3
> partd==1.4.0
> pathlib==1.0.1
> pathy==0.10.1
> patsy==0.5.3
> pexpect==4.8.0
> pickleshare==0.7.5
> Pillow==8.4.0
> pip-tools==6.13.0
> platformdirs==3.3.0
> plotly==5.13.1
> plotnine==0.10.1
> pluggy==1.0.0
> polars==0.17.3
> pooch==1.6.0
> portpicker==1.3.9
> prefetch-generator==1.0.3
> preshed==3.0.8
> prettytable==0.7.2
> proglog==0.1.10
> progressbar2==4.2.0
> prometheus-client==0.16.0
> promise==2.3
> prompt-toolkit==3.0.38
> prophet==1.1.3
> proto-plus==1.22.2
> protobuf==3.20.3
> psutil==5.9.5
> psycopg2==2.9.6
> ptyprocess==0.7.0
> py-cpuinfo==9.0.0
> py4j==0.10.9.7
> pyarrow==9.0.0
> pyasn1==0.5.0
> pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
> pycocotools==2.0.6
> pycparser==2.21
> pyct==0.5.0
> pydantic==1.10.7
> pydata-google-auth==1.7.0
> pydot==1.4.2
> pydot-ng==2.0.0
> pydotplus==2.0.2
> PyDrive==1.3.1
> pyerfa==2.0.0.3
> pygame==2.3.0
> Pygments==2.14.0
> PyGObject==3.36.0
> pymc==5.1.2
> PyMeeus==0.5.12
> pymystem3==0.2.0
> PyOpenGL==3.1.6
> pyparsing==3.0.9
> pyproject_hooks==1.0.0
> pyrsistent==0.19.3
> PySocks==1.7.1
> pytensor==2.10.1
> pytest==7.2.2
> python-apt==0.0.0
> python-dateutil==2.8.2
> python-louvain==0.16
> python-slugify==8.0.1
> python-utils==3.5.2
> pytz==2022.7.1
> pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
> pyviz-comms==2.2.1
> PyWavelets==1.4.1
> PyYAML==6.0
> pyzmq==23.2.1
> qdldl==0.1.7
> qudida==0.0.4
> regex==2022.10.31
> requests==2.27.1
> requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
> requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
> requirements-parser==0.5.0
> rich==13.3.4
> rpy2==3.5.5
> rsa==4.9
> scikit-image==0.19.3
> scikit-learn==1.2.2
> scipy==1.10.1
> scs==3.2.3
> seaborn==0.12.2
> Send2Trash==1.8.0
> shapely==2.0.1
> six==1.16.0
> sklearn-pandas==2.2.0
> smart-open==6.3.0
> sniffio==1.3.0
> snowballstemmer==2.2.0
> sortedcontainers==2.4.0
> soundfile==0.12.1
> soupsieve==2.4.1
> soxr==0.3.5
> spacy==3.5.2
> spacy-legacy==3.0.12
> spacy-loggers==1.0.4
> Sphinx==3.5.4
> sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.4
> sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
> sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.1
> sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
> sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
> sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.5
> SQLAlchemy==2.0.10
> sqlparse==0.4.4
> srsly==2.4.6
> statsmodels==0.13.5
> sympy==1.11.1
> tables==3.8.0
> tabulate==0.8.10
> tblib==1.7.0
> tenacity==8.2.2
> tensorboard==2.12.2
> tensorboard-data-server==0.7.0
> tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
> tensorflow==2.12.0
> tensorflow-datasets==4.9.2
> tensorflow-estimator==2.12.0
> tensorflow-gcs-config==2.12.0
> tensorflow-hub==0.13.0
> tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.32.0
> tensorflow-metadata==1.13.1
> tensorflow-probability==0.20.1
> tensorstore==0.1.36
> termcolor==2.3.0
> terminado==0.17.1
> text-unidecode==1.3
> textblob==0.17.1
> tf-slim==1.1.0
> thinc==8.1.9
> threadpoolctl==3.1.0
> tifffile==2023.4.12
> tinycss2==1.2.1
> toml==0.10.2
> tomli==2.0.1
> toolz==0.12.0
> torch 
> torchaudio 
> torchdata==0.6.1
> torchsummary==1.5.1
> torchtext==0.15.2
> torchvision 
> tornado==6.3.1
> tqdm==4.65.0
> traitlets==5.7.1
> triton==2.0.0
> tweepy==4.13.0
> typer==0.7.0
> types-setuptools==67.8.0.0
> typing_extensions==4.5.0
> tzdata==2023.3
> tzlocal==4.3
> uritemplate==4.1.1
> urllib3==1.26.15
> vega-datasets==0.9.0
> wasabi==1.1.1
> wcwidth==0.2.6
> webcolors==1.13
> webencodings==0.5.1
> websocket-client==1.5.1
> Werkzeug==2.3.0
> widgetsnbextension==3.6.4
> wordcloud==1.8.2.2
> wrapt==1.14.1
> xarray==2022.12.0
> xarray-einstats==0.5.1
> xgboost==1.7.5
> xlrd==2.0.1
> yellowbrick==1.5
> yfinance==0.2.18
> zict==3.0.0
> ```

Comment: What is the output of print(dir(gspread)) ?

Comment: @Itération122442 the output is ['Cell', 'CellNotFound', 'Client', 'GSpreadException', 'IncorrectCellLabel', 'NoValidUrlKeyFound', 'Spreadsheet', 'SpreadsheetNotFound', 'Worksheet', 'WorksheetNotFound', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'authorize', 'client', 'exceptions', 'models', 'urls', 'utils']

Comment: According to pypi inspector, the stuff you showed doesn't match what is really in the `gspread/__init__.py`.  So I have a question: Could you try doing pip freeze and showing us what you have? I worry you might've installed something else that shares the same namespace and it's importing that instead of the gspread you want

Comment: I browsed some packages on pypi and it seems you might've installed `gspreed` first - it has a colliding namespace (it seems to have started as a clone but it's old and abandoned - and author didn't really do any modifications) and the stuff in its space matches what you got from `dir(gspread)` - see https://inspector.pypi.io/project/gspreed/0.2.2/packages/17/aa/5610ac167b9036b54ceb713b4d41f728b67446dae6789e948902a7b52c78/gspreed-0.2.2.tar.gz/gspreed-0.2.2/gspread/__init__.py So `pip freeze` to confirm, `pip uninstall gspreed` to get rid of that, and try again

Comment: hey @h4z3 i tried doing pip freeze and also pip uninstall gspreed this was my output;                                 
.                                                             
.                                                             
googleapis-common-protos==1.59.0
googledrivedownloader==0.4
graphviz==0.20.1
greenlet==2.0.2
grpcio==1.54.0
grpcio-status==1.48.2
gs==1.1.1
gspread==5.9.0
gspread-dataframe==3.0.8
gym==0.25.2
gym-notices==0.0.8                                                              .

Comment: there was no gspreed found. i also got this message while attempting to uninstall gspreed: WARNING: Skipping gspreed as it is not installed.

Comment: Check the spelling, it looks like h4z3 made a typo "gspreed" instead of "gspread". I usually try to type rather than paste what comes from answers and comments if it's reasonable to do so. :)

Comment: @Vaz no, not a typo. I specifically said there's a pypi package with EE instead of EA that imports the same (EA) and would collide with it. See the link I posted. Quoting myself: `I browsed some packages on pypi and it seems you might've installed gspreed first - it has a colliding namespace (it seems to have started as a clone but it's old and abandoned - and author didn't really do any modifications)` - colliding namespace == colliding name of import, despite different pip install name

Comment: @CYBER1C could you please put whole pip freeze in the question? I browsed the packages you listed and they seem fine, but it could be something else, not starting with g :P

Comment: @CYBER1C ...wow. My first recommendation would be to learn about virtual environments. That would also make collisions of packages really rare. Because in here (global install of python) you have so many packages that it's impossible to browse them...

Comment: @h4z3 sorry about that, my bad. I guess if anyone else reads these comments maybe my confusion and your clarification will help them avoid the same mistake I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the following code:

```
from gspread import authorize
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scopes = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
cred = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("link_to_the_credentials", scopes)
gclient = authorize(cred)
```

I found the solution on their documentation page, Aparently it is the longer version of the service_account method used in the earlier versions.
You can read more about it at; https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.9.0/oauth2.html